# Is there a TreeVisitor for visiting expression trees in evaluation order?

Tags: java, expression-trees, visitor-pattern, java-compiler-api

Using the Java Compiler Tree API, one can traverse the leaf tree of a `TreePath` and its children using a [`TreeVisitor`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/jdk/api/javac/tree/com/sun/source/tree/TreeVisitor.html).

Is there a `TreeVisitor` implementation that visits all "nodes" in evaluation order? For example, if `7 - 8 * 2 + 10` were parsed as:

```
        _____+__
       /        \
      -          10
     / \
    7   *
       / \
      8   2
```

Is there a `TreeVisitor` that will visit the [`BinaryTree`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/jdk/api/javac/tree/com/sun/source/tree/BinaryTree.html) for `8 * 2` followed by the `BinaryTree` for `7 - (8 * 2)`, then the `BinaryTree` for `(7 - (8 * 2)) + 10`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Where better to look than the source of `javac` ([langtools](http://openjdk.java.net/groups/compiler/))!

In the Analyze and Generate [phase of compilation](http://openjdk.java.net/groups/compiler/doc/compilation-overview/index.html), multiple passes are made through each compilation unit syntax tree. One pass in particular, Gen, generates the bytecode compilations of method implementations. The bulk of the Gen pass is apparently in [`com.sun.tools.javac.jvm.Gen`](http://hg.openjdk.java.net/jdk7/jdk7/langtools/file/tip/src/share/classes/com/sun/tools/javac/jvm/Gen.java), which implements `JCTree.Visitor`.